# Why is root in sudoers file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, root

I couldn't help but notice the line in the sudoers file:

root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

From what I understand root already has superuser privileges and doesn't really need to use sudo at all. Am I missing something? Why would root have default sudo privileges when, even when removed from this file, can still do everything it could before?
Sorry if the answer is obvious I'm new to linux

Comment: sudo isn't just for becoming *root*. Much like su.

Comment: scripts that use sudo would fail for root otherwise

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `sudo` is to impersonate another user. Root has plenty of reasons to impersonate other users, e.g. testing whether service accounts are set up correctly.

Also, you overlooked a key word in your own question [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> From what I understand root already has superuser privileges and doesn't really **need** to use sudo at all.

Sure, root doesn't *need* to use `sudo`, but they still might accidentally *type* `sudo`, and it would be pretty annoying if the command then fails because root is not allowed to use `sudo`.

It would also make it awkward to write scripts which use `sudo` and may or may not run under the root account.